# <svg> <use> in edge doesn't appear [angular 2]

Tags: angularjs, angular, svg, microsoft-edge

I have this code, which works perfectly fine in chrome:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...some tags
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
       <g id="overview">
         <path data-name="overview" d="M12.5,0A12.5,12.5,0,1,0,25,12.5h0A12.5,12.5,0,0,0,12.5,0Zm0,19C7.22,19,3,12.5,3,12.5S7.22,6,12.5,6,22,12.5,22,12.5,17.78,19,12.5,19Zm0-9.49a3,3,0,1,0,3,3,3,3,0,0,0-3-3Z"/>
       </g>
    </svg>
    <app>
      ..some tags
      <svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" width="25" height="25">
         <use xlink:href="#overview" />
      </svg>
      ..some tags
    </app>
  </body>
</html>
```

But in edge, I see nothing.
Also tried to add color to it (with `fill`). again, works in chrome, not in edge

**NOTE**
It's an angular 2 app, so the `svg` with the `use` tag is inside the angular component and rendered with angular compiler

Comment: Excluding the `xlink:` will not work in any browser except Chrome. Please add a full [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. What you have posted here is not enough to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I can add the all code, but it is very long. trying to keep it as simple as possible. Edited. What else you need to have?

Comment: which one your correct `svg` code?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Firefox 51+ supports href without xlink:

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah ok. Thanks Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using AngularJS is a big clue.

Check your page.  If you are using angular routing, then your header may have a `<base>` tag.  If that is the case, then your `<use>` references will need to include the page URL as well - otherwise they will be affected by the `<base>` like other references.

In other words, you would have to do something like:

```
<use xlink:href="this-file.html#overview" />
```

or possibly

```
<use xlink:href="/path/to/this/file.html#overview" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I extracted the svg to an external file, so it won't be affected by the router